# Ember DRY nested components with same actions

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-router, ember-components

Right now I am building a particular screen within my ember app that
has an unknown number of nested components. Because of this I am trying not
to change the url based on the component being shown also there is some base info
I want to display on every sub screen.

Currently it seems like I have to redefine and pass in all these action names everywhere when the real action logic is only defined on the route. Is there a way
to DRY these action references possibly in a controller or one "parent" component.

here is an example ember-twiddle where I am rendering these components into an outlet http://ember-twiddle.com/31a69c62ceddcb69b02b

here is an example of the route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  _fixtureModels: [
    { person: {name: 'bill'}, sideModel: null},
    { person: {name: 'bill'}, sideModel: { postName: 'test post' }},
    { person: {name: 'bill'}, sideModel: { commentName: 'test comment'}}
    ],

  _renderSideModel: function (template, sideModel) {
    this.render();

    this.render(template, {
      outlet: 'side-model',
      into: 'index',
      model: sideModel
    });
  },

  renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render();

   this.render('someComponentWrapper', {
     outlet: 'side-model',
     into: 'index'
   });
  },

  model: function () {
     return this._fixtureModels[0];
  },

  actions: {
    renderTopLevel: function () {
      return this.renderTemplate();
    },
    renderPost: function () {
      return this._renderSideModel('post', this._fixtureModels[1]);
    },
    renderComment: function () {
      return this._renderSideModel('comment', this._fixtureModels[2]);
    }
  }
});
```

I know URL is supposed to be king in Ember and this is pretty sinful but it would be very hard to reconstruct a potentially nested view.

Comment: Technically, your component actions should bubble up ending in controller and route. 
Also you can specify your target object from a component

Comment: @abFx component actions do not bubble.

Comment: @BillPull Thanks for using Ember Twiddle. Please be sure to leave feedback.

Comment: @Gaurav check this out ... http://ember-twiddle.com/dd5b9636b5ced43dd440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason you have to redefine all these action names is because components are designed to be isolated, i.e. reused anywhere. There are however, two shortcuts you can use:

1. Apply default action names:

You can use a default action name in your component to avoid having to specify it in every template.

```
// components/some-component.js

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    renderPost: "renderPost",
    renderComment: "renderComment"
});

// some template where you are using this component

{{some-component-wrapper renderPost="myRenderPost"}}
{{!overrides renderPost, but "inherits" an action named renderComment}}
```

2. Use closure actions (if you are using Ember 1.13 or later):

See http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_closure-actions

This is a new feature that lets you pass a function down rather than a name of an action.